# If I do a fulltext index search but limit the number of results, does MySql always give me the best matches?

Tags: mysql, database, search, full-text-search

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (title, description, tags) AGAINST ('$query') LIMIT 10;
```

If not, how can I ensure it will return the ten best results? Thanks

Comment: write like this it always show top ten result: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (title, description, tags) AGAINST ('$query') id ASC LIMIT 10`

Comment: Sorry I meant the 10 best results. ie. closest matches. Will edit. ;)

Comment: what do you mean by best result?

Comment: Closest match to query. Does MySQL query the entire dataset first then return the best matches first in the case of a `LIMIT` clause?